# Where can I download WampServer for Windows XP 32-bit?

Tags: windows-xp, wamp

Where can I download WampServer for Windows XP 32-bit?

Answer (score 1):

How about this? http://www.wampserver.com/en/ At the download page, the top link actually points to the 32 bits version... I think it's a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You have another free alternative in [WAMPStack](http://bitnami.org/stack/wampstack) from [BitNami](http://bitnami.org), as well.

Answer (score 0):

WampServer is available for free (under GPML license) in two distinct versions : 32 and 64 bits. Wampserver 2.5 is not compatible with Windows XP, neither with SP3, nor Windows Server 2003. Older WampServer versions are available on SourceForge.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/?source=navbar